# How to prevent serialization of read only collection properties using System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

Create a class with a read-only collection property.
Serialize using `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` with options to specify `IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true`.
Read only collection properties are still being serialized, whereas other read only properties are not serialized.
Upon deserializing all read only properties are ignored as expected.

Why are collections treated differently upon serialization?

Can I prevent serialization of a read only collection property without `[JsonIgnore]` attributes?

The choice of serialization method is out of my hands so I am hoping to have no serialization specific attributes in my code.

With the following test class:

```
public class TestJSONClass
{
   public int ReadOnlyInt { get; } = 1;
   public IEnumerable<int> ReadOnlyCollection { get; } = new int[2];

   public int ReadWriteInt { get; set; } = 3;
   public IEnumerable<int> ReadWriteCollection { get; set; } = new int[4];
}
```

Then serialized by:

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true, IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true };
JsonSerializer.Serialize(new TestJSONClass(), options);
```

I get the output below.
As expected `ReadOnlyInt` is not serialized.
However, `ReadOnlyCollection` *is* serialized.

```
{
  "ReadOnlyCollection": [
    0,
    0
  ],
  "ReadWriteInt": 3,
  "ReadWriteCollection": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
}
```

I aim to get the following:

```
{
  "ReadWriteInt": 3,
  "ReadWriteCollection": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `IgnoreReadOnlyProperties/Fields = true` does not apply to
> Collections.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/37599#issuecomment-669742740

The reason is to ensure that rule CA2227 can be applied and still use JsonSerializer to deserialize a collection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2227?view=vs-2019

My best guess is using [JsonIgnore]. If you cannot or don't want to use it, you could write your own converter/rules. But I think that isn't easy at all.

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways how to avoid serialization of a property is to mark the property as internal, then it won't be serialized.

So in your case, change your line

```
public IEnumerable<int> ReadOnlyCollection { get; } = new int[2];
```

to

```
internal IEnumerable<int> ReadOnlyCollection { get; } = new int[2];
```

You will get the following result:

```
{
  "ReadWriteInt": 3,
  "ReadWriteCollection": [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
  ]
}
```

Comment: Cheers, while a good workaround for the specific problem, unfortunately it is a requirement for the collection to be public. My alternative workaround is to make it a public method at the moment.